# How do I resize an ext3 partition that is not part of a LVM group?

Tags: partition

I've read various questions/answers such as this one:

> [How to extend CentOS 5 partition on VMware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42857/how-to-extend-centos-5-partition-on-vmware)

However I have an ext3 partition I need to extend that isn't part of a LVM group and never will be.

What steps do I need to take to achieve this without losing data?

I'm running CentOS 6.4 x64 (text only, no GUI/X etc) on XenServer. I've already resized the XenServer virtual disk that the partition (`/dev/xvdb1`) resides on (it's the only partition).

Answer (score 2):

If you have `parted` 3.2, then you can use its `resizepart` command to enlarge the partition.  Otherwise, you need to `print` the existing partition table after setting it to use sectors with `unit s`.  In your case the partition almost certainly starts on sector 2048.  Delete the partition with the `rm` command, then recreate it with `mkpart`, make sure it starts on the same sector, and have it use the new, larger "disk" size.

After that, you need to resize the filesystem.  For ext[234], you do that using `resizepart /dev/xvdb1`.

Comment: Sadly CentOS 6.4 doesn't ship with a more modern `parted` releases, 2.1 is current version in base repo.

Comment: @Kev, that version is quite ancient, so you may want to compile it from source yourself.  At the very least, using that old version will cause it to fail to update the kernel and you will have to reboot for the changes to take affect.

Comment: We have a standard policy which is that we can only use CentOS or EPEL repos.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a normal partition (PC BIOS or GPT).

1. You really should make a backup of the partition table (e.g. with `sfdisk -d /dev/sda` or `parted /dev/sda "unit s" print`)
2. You have to make sure that there is free space behind the partition.
3. If you don't have a tool which allows to extend a partition directly then you have to delete the partition and recreate it at the same sector but with bigger size.
4. Once you've enlarged the partition, run `resize2fs /dev/xvdb1` to enlarge the filesystem to span the whole partition.

Comment: "delete the partition"? Won't that cause me to lose all the data on the partition?

Comment: @Kev Like (normal) deleting a file deleting a partition does not touch the data but only the pointer to the partition. You can delete a partition within a fraction of a second although overwriting the data in a large partition would take minutes.